# Check if a string matches a regex in Unix

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I have a script which takes a string input from the user. The input is kind of a release version and it has a certain format - `5.80.0-05`
How do i validate this and make sure the user is entering it in this format only.

Let me know if someone can advice. I am not very good with regex's

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @anubhava I don't know how to start. Was just looking at the syntax but not sure if i understand it correctly. I know this is not how this site works but I have no clue where to start. So if you can just give me a bit of push or link somewhere, I can work it out

Comment: For not-so-strict check use: `^[0-9.-]+$` as regex

Comment: One problem is that based on a single example without extra requirements, it's hard to tell what the pattern is. That can range from "any string consisting of digits, periods and dashes" to "three numbers separated by periods, one dash and another number", and the first three numbers probably shouldn't start with `0` etc.

Comment: To start, know that the pattern `[0-9]` matches a single digit, and pattern `[.]` matches a single `.` character.

Comment: Read over [this guiide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and clarify your spec. Try a few things, show us what you tried and why/how if it didn't work. [Do your research.](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+regex) http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script sniplet could help you.
I don't know the *exact* pattern that you wish to check against, but the regex syntax below should be easily adjustable if your pattern differs:

```
#!/bin/bash
version=${1}

[[ "$version" =~ ^[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]-[0-9]{2}$ ]] || echo Wrong input format: $version
```